# Как установить Django Blog Zinnia?

Tags: установка, django, postgresql, ubuntu

Подскажите, как мне установить Django, Blog, Zinnia на Ubuntu + PostgreSQL.

Желательно опишите поэтапно...

**Добавлено из комментариев**.

Что мне нужно делать после этих действий?

```
$ git clone git://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia.git$ cd django-blog-zinnia$ python setup.py install
```

Пользуюсь [гайдом](http://django-blog-zinnia.com/documentation/getting-started/install/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Джанго-то стоит?? в контекст-процессоры добавляем (см. подборку полезных советов http://eug.net-ko.net/weblog/tags/Zinnia/)

'zinnia.context_processors.media','zinnia.context_processors.version',(в инструкции один пропущен!)Не помню - нужно ли статик файлы выуживать - это видно при первом запуске. Выполняем дальше всю инструкцию.Рестартуем сайт.Зайти в админку - должен появиться раздел Zinnia, написать первый пост. Не забыть ему поменять тип с "черновик" на "опубликован".Зайти на /weblog сайта - там есть Цинния?А если Джанго не стоит - см. мануал по ее установке... :)